# Micronaut Data DTO projection with properties from joined entities

Tags: java, jpa, micronaut, micronaut-data

I use Micronaut Data with JPA and have two entities. The first one is `Recipe`:

```java
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Step> steps;

// + other fields, getters and setters
}
```

The second one is `ParseError` which refers to `Recipe`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "parse_error")
public class ParseError implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Recipe recipe;

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "problem_area")
    private ProblemArea problemArea;

    private String message;

// + other fields, getters and setters
}
```

Now I would like to provide DTO in API with `ParseError` properties but not with whole `Recipe` entity because it contains ManyToOne and OneToMany relations which are not needed in this case. So I created projection DTO for that:

```java
@Introspected
public class ParseErrorDto {
    private Integer recipeId;

    private String recipeName;

    private ParseError.ProblemArea problemArea;

    private String message;

// + getters and setters
}
```

And added `listAll()` method into `ParseErrorRepository`:

```java
@Repository
public interface ParseErrorRepository extends CrudRepository<ParseError, Integer> {
    List<ParseErrorDto> listAll();
}
```

But it seems that Micronaut Data is not able to project properties from nested entities or I missed something in the DTO or the repository method:

> ParseErrorRepository.java:22: error: Unable to implement Repository
>   method: ParseErrorRepository.listAll(). Property recipeId is not
>   present in entity: ParseError

I also tried to create `RecipeDto`:

```java
@Introspected
public class RecipeDto {
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    // + getters and setters
}
```

And updated `ParseErrorDto` accordingly:

```java
@Introspected
public class ParseErrorDto {
    private RecipeDto recipe;

    private ParseError.ProblemArea problemArea;

    private String message;

    // + getters and setters
}
```

Again no success:

> ParseErrorRepository.java:22: error: Unable to implement Repository
>   method: ParseErrorRepository.listAll(). Property [recipe] of type
>   [RecipeDto] is not compatible with equivalent property declared in
>   entity: ParseError

Is Micronaut Data able to handle this use case by DTO projection? If not then is there another way how can I solve it in Micronaut Data?

Comment: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/issues/170

Comment: @SaschaFrinken it is a different issue, but I created the new one especially for this case: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/issues/184

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now (in latest version 1.0.0.M1) it is not possible. So I created feature request issue for that: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/issues/184

Current workaround is to map entity bean into DTO bean in Java stream or reactive stream for example and do the properties mapping manually or by Mapstruct.

---

**Update:** Here is an answer to question from comments with an example how to do the workaround using Mapstruct:

Add Mapstruct dependency into *build.gradle*:

```
implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:$mapstructVersion"
annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:$mapstructVersion"
testAnnotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:$mapstructVersion"
```

Define mapper:

```java
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

@Mapper(
    componentModel = "jsr330"
)
public interface ParseErrorMapper {
    ParseErrorDto entityToDto(@NotNull ParseError parseError);

    EntityReference recipeToDto(@NotNull Recipe recipe);
}
```

And here is a usage of that mapper in the controller:

```java
@Controller("/parse-error")
public class ParseErrorController {
    private final ParseErrorRepository repository;
    private final ParseErrorMapper mapper;

    public ParseErrorController(ParseErrorRepository repository, ParseErrorMapper mapper) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Get("all")
    @Transactional
    public Page<ParseErrorDto> getAll(final Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findAll(pageable).map(mapper::entityToDto);
    }
}
```

**Update (September 2023):** feature implemented by https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/pull/2495

Comment: Hey, I have currently the same problem,... Can you maybe provide an example of the 'manually' mapping? I have several parts in my application where I need something like an converter and I don't know 'what is the best way' to do it.

Comment: I added example of how I solved that using Mapstruct.